# How to fill ArrayList in a loop, when size is not known?

Tags: java, android

I have to fill members of some objects, but I don't know how many are them. That's why I'm using ArrayList because of dynamic size. But I don't know how to fill these objects in ArrayList. I'm reading line by line from file and if I found my match pattern, I have to create new object and fill it with data.

```
//read data from file to BufferedReader, that we can read out single line by line
BufferedReader mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mFile));
String line;

while ((line = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    //pattern "name" for searching points
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
    //array of delimited Strings separated with comma 
    String[] delimitedStrings = line.split(",");

    //if we find "name" of point, get code, lat and lon of that point
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        String name = delimitedStrings[0];
        mData.add(new myData().name = name);
        String code = delimitedStrings[1];
        mData.add(new myData().code = code);

    }
}
```

myData class has members String name, String code for example. I need something like this with add method, but that is not working. Thanks!

Comment: what does "that is not working" mean ?

Comment: please provide what exactly do you want to do, explain more

as for not knowing how much number of object are there, while is okay

Comment: That I need something like this mData.add(new myData().name = name), but this is not correct syntax, it's just my example what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit vague but maybe you meant this

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    String name = delimitedStrings[0];
    String code = delimitedStrings[1];

    mTaskData.add(new MyData(name, code));                    
}
```

where `MyData` class has a constructor defined as

```
public class MyData {

    private String name;
    private String code;

    public MyData (String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    // getters/setters()
}
```

Also, the `Pattern` doesn't change so should be moved out of the file reader loop.

```
// compile the pattern just once (outside the loop)
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");

while ((line = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, I forgot that values could be pass by constructor. Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

This won't compile:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    String name = delimitedStrings[0];
    mTaskData.add(new myData().name = name);                

    String code = delimitedStrings[1];
    mTaskData.add(new myData().code = code);                    

}
```

should be like this:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    String name = delimitedStrings[0];
    myData md = new myData();
    md.name = name; // or use setter like md.setName(name)
    mTaskData.add(md);                

    String code = delimitedStrings[1];
    md.code = code;
    mTaskData.add(md);                    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<mData> mData = new ArrayList<>();

mData.add(new mData(code));
```

make a constructor in mData with parameter String code